# On random numbers extracted from NormalDistribution by two different methods under the same seed

Tags: functions, random, internals

I've encountered the following situation within various trials.

Why does such a difference arise between bulk sampling and one-by-one sampling?

```
(*Bulk sampling*)
SeedRandom[1234];
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10]

(*sampling one-by-one*)
SeedRandom[1234];
Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], 10]
```

[image]

Example:
For example, consider the following game.

- The player gains points depending on the value of **variable x** every time.
- x is a random number, and is subject to NormalDistribution [0, 1]
- If **x> 0** then the player gets **+ 1**,otherwise, **x <0**, the player gets **-1**.

I believed that **expectation value of game scores should be equal regardless of how random numbers are generated.**

However, the experiment is as follows.
About Mean:

```
{BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1234]; 
  N@Mean@Table[
     Total[If[# > 0, 1, -1] & /@ 
       RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10]], {100}]],
 BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1234]; 
  N@Mean@Table[
     Total[If[# > 0, 1, -1] & /@ 
       Table[First@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1], 
        10]], {100}]]}
```

> {0.18, -0.68}

```
Histogram[{BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1234]; 
   Table[Total[
     If[# > 0, 1, -1] & /@ 
      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10]], {100}]],
  BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1234]; 
   Table[Total[
     If[# > 0, 1, -1] & /@ 
      Table[First@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 1], 
       10]], {100}]]}]
```

[image]

I didn't understand why this happens and found out the phenomenon in this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89161/discussion-on-question-by-xminer-on-random-numbers-extracted-from-normaldistribu).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this is due to the [Box–Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) that is employed to generate *pairs* of normally distributed values. This method is *much* faster than using the inverse commulative probability function.

The algorithm is essentially as follows:

```
n = 1000000;
a = Flatten[ReIm[
   Times[
    Sqrt[-2. Log[RandomReal[{0, 1}, n]]],
    Exp[(2. Pi I) RandomReal[{0, 1}, n]]
    ]
   ]]; // AbsoluteTiming //First
```

> 0.003597

As comparison:

```
b = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2 n]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Histogram[{a, b}]
```

> 0.003579

[image]

Although I cannot reproduce the precise order used in *Mathematica*, the timings are very similar. I guess, this supports my hypothesis.

**Whenever only a single sampling of the normal distribution is required, the second sampled value is just thrown away.** This explains why the results of the bulk sampling equal the results one-by-one sampling, interleaved with other pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: Box-Muller generates two independent Normals. What difference does it make if you drop one of them? None.

Comment: @wolfies Well, the results of `SeedRandom[1234]; RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10]` and `SeedRandom[1234]; Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], 10]` _are_ different. But one would not expect that. For example, `SeedRandom[1234]; RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], 10]
SeedRandom[1234]; Table[RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1]], 10]` return _exactly_ the same result.

Comment: I don't agree that there is any guarantee or requirement that calling 10 pseudorandom numbers from a particular distribution all in one go is required to use the same generator as calling one pseudorandom number at a time. Indeed, if code is well-optimised, one might expect that different algorithms are used to generate multiple values all in one go, rather than single ones. The very same thing happens with the `LogNormalDistribution` and `HalfNormalDistribution`, possibly because they use the Normal generator.

Comment: At the same time, +1 on your very fine (!) sleuthing and explanation as the likely cause and the algorithms being used.

Answer (score 4):

When I change the distribution from `NormalDistribution` to `UniformDistribution` there is no difference in the two results.

```
SeedRandom[1234];
RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], 10]
```

> `{0.876608, 0.521964, 0.0862234, 0.377913, 0.0116446, 0.927266, 0.543757, 0.479332, 0.245349, 0.759896}`

```
SeedRandom[1234];
Table[First @ RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], 1], 10]
```

> `{0.876608, 0.521964, 0.0862234, 0.377913, 0.0116446, 0.927266, 0.543757, 0.479332, 0.245349, 0.759896}`

From this I conclude that the anomalous behavior is caused by the distribution function and not by `RandomVariate`. This is additional support for Henrik Schumacher's hypothesis.